# What curve is this and where is it used?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, curves

While playing around with the normal distribution, or more precisely, the probability density function:

$$\displaystyle f(x | \mu,\sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} e^{- \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$$

I calculated the following curve:

[image]

The formula for this is just:
$$f(x | \mu,\sigma^2) = pdf(x) - pdf(x-1)$$

It reminded me of an heart beat. What curve is this? Is this curve used anywhere?

I'm sorry if this is a simple question, I'm a little bad at mathematics.

Comment: This curve is effectively equivalent to $$\large{f(x)=ae^{-(bx)^2}\sinh{(bx)}}$$

Comment: @PeterForeman if instead of $pdf(x)-pdf(x-1)$ I use $pdf(x-1)-pdf(x)$ it is the same curve. Is that curve used anywhere?